# Change value of var outside the function

Tags: ios, swift, func

I declared the `var imagePicked = 0` at the top of my class.
Now when I change the value of imagePicked inside an IBAction like here:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var titelbild: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var profilbild: UIButton!


let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
var imagePicked = 0



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    imagePicker.delegate = self
 //   imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
  //  imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func titelbildtapped(sender: AnyObject) {


 //   if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){


    imagePicked == 1

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary


        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)



  //  }


}


@IBAction func profilbildtapped(sender: AnyObject) {


    imagePicked == 2

        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary


        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print ("output")

}





func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {


if imagePicked == 1 {

    titelbild.setImage(pickedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
       // titelbild.imageView?.image = pickedImage

 } else if imagePicked == 2 {
        profilbild.setImage(pickedImage, forState: .Normal)        }

    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}



func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

the value of imagePicked appears to be still 0 instead of 2. How can I change the value of it, so it is not only changed inside the function i changed it?

Comment: can you show a complete sample of your class? cause normally your code should work - except the example function should be something like `func example() { ... }`...

Comment: Did you really write imagePicked == 2 instead if imagePicked = 2 ?

Comment: put a `print` output into your `profilbildtapped` function to see if it really gets called when you tap on your imageview...

Comment: @AndréSlotta just tested, it really get´s called

Comment: can you please show the **complete** class? so that i can see where you declare `imagePicked`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. the problem is in your `titelbildtapped` / `profilbildtapped` functions. there you have to assign the values **1** / **2** with a single **=** instead of double **==** which checks for equality.

so change `imagePicked == 1` / `imagePicked == 2` to `imagePicked = 1` / `imagePicked = 2` in those functions and it should work!